# Velocity equations in parabolic motion of projectiles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

What are  the equations to calculate the velocity IN ANY MOMENT of a projectile in parabolic motion? I assume that they depends of the angle of the projectile that it has in any moment, not when $t=0$.

Comment: -1. This question shows no research effort. There are many website which will give you this information. Also questions on this site such as [Obtaining a general equation for velocity (in 2-D projectile motion)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338869) and [Projectile motion formulas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79030)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming launch at velocity $V$,  at elevation angle $\theta$:
$$V_x=V\times \cos(x)$$ $$ V_y = V\times \sin(\theta )-gt$$

Invers tan of $\frac {V_y}{V_x}$  gives the instantaneous velocity direction;  Pythagoras gives the instantaneous velocity magnitude

Comment: I would just add that the angle it has at that moment is irrelevant. As you can see from the equation it depends on the initial angle and velocity and how much time the acceleration due to gravity has had to affect it.

Comment: OP asked for the velocity; for a vector,  magnitude and direction would both seem to be necessary...

Comment: Are you talking to me? B/C I'm referring to OP's statement; " I assume that they depends of the angle of the projectile that it has in any moment" - No, it doesn't.  (nothing wrong with your answer)

Comment: Given that the vector of instantaneous velocitiy is a tangent vector to trajectory, is obvious that it have a different angle for every moment; hence, it's necessary to take this precise angle in the equations exposed above and NOT the initial angle of launch. In any case, this question must be verifyed by experimentation. I suppose, e.g. that army engineers know 'something' about this for the simple reason that the linear momentum of the projectile in the moment of impact to target determines his 'power of destruction'.